# Computer cpu usage drops to 0-5% seemingly randomly along with fan speed, causing apps and games to freeze and sometimes crash

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, fan, cpu-usage

technical difficulties here, from my recent searches i thing this is the appropriate place to look for help?. Computer CPU randomly drops to 0% along with the fan suddenly slowing down and going back up again.

cpu temperature is always at 28-30% according to [open harware monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/).

I have attempted to update all my drivers and reinstall my graphics drivers, though if they are up to date I am not sure since i used [Driver Booster](https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php).

I have run all the system and disk fix commands i found online from similar problems: `sfc /scannow ; dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth ; chkdsk *: /f /r;` and running windows memory diagnostic(i got a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT blue screen once.), also reinstalling the vcredist packages.

After all of this i have noticed that the problem started occurring with less frequency, but still happening when idle, and consistently happening when running windows antivirus or downloading anything.

please help.

//------------System info------------//

Device name DESKTOP-P3SP64E

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz   3.91 GHz

Installed RAM   16.0 GB

Device ID   14B92DC8-B5DC-442A-BD98-344DB933FE63

Product ID  00331-60000-00000-AA705

System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

System Manufacturer BIOSTAR Group

System Model    H110MG PRO D4

BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 5.12, 7/21/2017

Edition Windows 10 Pro N

Version 22H2

Installed on    ‎10/‎2/‎2022

OS build    19045.2193

Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0

Graphic Card    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

//------------------------//

Comment: I am not clear on your issue. My computers (CPU) run at about 5% more than 90 to 95% of the time. Fan is always on low except when there is a load for a few seconds.  Seems normal to me

Comment: well, you see, for example: i'm either playing a game or watching videos on youtube, then suddenly the cpu fan drastically slows down and cpu usage goes from 80-90% to 0-5%, freezing the whole desktop, sometimes crashing the app i'm using, and getting a bluscreen once (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT). and this occurs semi-frequently, more when i'm running more heavy apps like a open-world game.

Comment: and about the fan, to clarify more, normally it's always at a good constant speed (it's default is very loud), and it feels like the fan is stepping on the brakes with how sudden and fast it slows down.

Comment: Try updating BIOS and any Power drivers.  Reset the power plan to Windows default.

Comment: I'd throw out Driver Booster, then reset the machine to defaults. Start over. Don't use 3rd party 'optimisers' at all, they're more trouble than they're worth. IOBit are not the worst, but just avoid this stuff entirely. They offer to install things that are either entirely unnecessary, or even damaging & counter-productive.